# Using BigQuery as a datastorage/cache system for google sheets addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I have a google sheets addon with custom formulas that fetch data from my API to show in their result.
The problem for many users is the addon frequently reaches the Urlfetch quota. So I'm trying to use another source of data for my formulas, I been trying to setup BigQuery for that ( I know is not meant to be used like that).
My approach would be something like this:
When a user executes a formula, I look first in BigQuery to see if data already there, if not fetch from API then stores the result in a BigQuery.

I tried a proof of concept, where I added a custom function to my addon with the code sample in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery
where I replaced projectId for my own and queried a sample table
when executed the formula got this error:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to bigquery.jobs.query failed with error: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.

I tried also execute the same code from a function called from the sidebar frontend, where I got this error instead:

> User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project

From these errors I'm guessing I have to assign a BigQuery role in IAM to each user. But I have hundreds of them.
Is there any why that any addon user can access the BigQuery project? or my whole approach is wrong.

Comment: Since the app-script is closed source, you can use there a service account to query the data from your project. You provide all the data for the user by your API? Otherwise it would not be a good idea to store all the privat data from your customers in your system. Your app-script can directly query your data in your BigQuery project. BigQuery can also abtain data by starting Cloud Functions.

Comment: Hi Samuel, the formula result data comes entirely from the API, and is not user private data, for example if the result of =F(x) is 1 for user A, user B could get that 1 "cached" if he uses the same formula. If you could elaborate the first part of your comment in an answer that would be great!

Answer (score 2):

How about using the [Cache service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache) instead of BigQuery? The Cache service is simple to use, does not require authentication, and also works in a custom function context.

Note these limitations:

- The maximum length of a key is 250 characters.
- The maximum amount of data that can be stored per key is 100KB.
- The maximum  expiration time is 21,600 seconds (6 hours), but cached data may be removed before this time if a lot of data is cached.
- The cap for cached items is 1,000. If more than 1,000 items are written, the cache stores the 900 items farthest from expiration.

Comment: I plan of using cache aswell but as you said is a very limited solution for the demand we are having, that makes the addon unusable

Comment: I trust that you have already profiled how the most often used queries would hit the cache. 1,000 cached values is plenty for many use cases, but will obviously not be enough for larger scale applications.